# Linksys WMP110 works on fresh installation, but won't work after reboot

Tags: wireless, atheros

I've been at this for 2 weeks now, with no consistent success. The above NIC will work on a brand new install of most distros, but after a reboot or 2 will not connect. WICD gives the bad password error, ndiswrapper doesn't work, and manually managing wpa_supplicant via wpa_gui also doesn't connect. The network is always seen, just can't connect. The router is set to AES or TKIP. This same computer/NIC will connect under Windows. All other devices connect. Other distros on other computers connect. Info follows:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux DellDE051 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:31:42 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

01:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR5416 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5008 802.11(a)bgn] [168c:0023] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Linksys WMP110 v1 802.11n RangePlus Wireless PCI Adapter [1737:0072]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
01:08.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82562EZ 10/100 Ethernet Controller [8086:1050] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:01d5]
    Kernel driver in use: e100

##### lsusb #####

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 413c:3200 Dell Computer Corp. Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### iw reg get #####

##### interfaces #####

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=27 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e100
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.102
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             216.144.187.199
    DNS:             24.229.54.212
    DNS:             204.186.80.229

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ath9k
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 
    No Rent No Wi-Fi:Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 89 WPA2
    WIN_be68:        Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 82 WPA2
    LinksysE:        Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 90 WEP
    cisco:           Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA WPA2
    WIN_c673:        Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 87 WPA WPA2
    linksys:         Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 77 WPA

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"cisco"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000138034b13d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 60ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0005636973636F
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B10
                    IE: Unknown: 33082001020304050607
                    IE: Unknown: 33082105060708090A0B
                    IE: Unknown: DD270050F204104A0001101044000102104700102880288028801880A880002129D9A1AE103C000101
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEE1117FFFF0000010000000000000000000000000C0000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601050700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C33EE1117FFFF0000010000000000000000000000000C0000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C3401050700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4307000000
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"No Rent No Wi-Fi"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001402deb180
                    Extra: Last beacon: 320ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00104E6F2052656E74204E6F2057692D4669
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 050401020000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A6F1003FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000406E6E70D00
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606001500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101820003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C336F1003FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000406E6E70D00
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C3406001500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F204104A00011010440001021049000600372A000120

##### iwlist channel #####

wlan0     11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz

##### lsmod #####

ath9k                 144602  0 
ath9k_common           13359  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              438205  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    23922  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              545990  1 ath9k
cfg80211              409394  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211

##### modinfo #####

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     BAF225EEB618908380B28DA
alias:          platform:qca955x_wmac
alias:          platform:ar934x_wmac
alias:          platform:ar933x_wmac
alias:          platform:ath9k
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000185Fsd00003027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd00002810bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Fsd00007202bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd00002130bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000612bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000652bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000642bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd0000302Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Bbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001028sd0000020Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000103Csd0000217Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000103Csd000018E3bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000017AAsd00003026bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd0000213Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000662bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000672bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000622bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000185Fsd00003028bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E069bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd0000302Bbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003026bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd00002812bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd00002811bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00006671bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000632bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000185Fsd0000A119bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E068bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd00002176bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003028bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000037sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000010CFsd00001783bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000014CDsd00000064bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000014CDsd00000063bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv0000103Csd00001864bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000011ADsd00006641bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000011ADsd00006631bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001043sd0000850Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001A3Bsd00002110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001969sd00000091bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000017AAsd00003214bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv0000168Csd00003117bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000011ADsd00006661bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001A3Bsd00002116bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000033sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001043sd0000850Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00001C01bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00001C00bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001F95bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001195bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001F86bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001186bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00002001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00002000bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Fsd00007197bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000105Bsd0000E04Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000105Bsd0000E04Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000011ADsd00006628bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000011ADsd00006627bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001C56sd00004001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002100bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002C97bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000017AAsd00003219bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000017AAsd00003218bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000C708bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000C680bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000C706bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000410Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000410Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000410Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd00004106bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd00004105bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000185Fsd00003027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000185Fsd00003119bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000168Csd00003122bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000168Csd00003119bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000105Bsd0000E075bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002152bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd0000126Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002126bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001237bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002086bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000030sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Bsv00001A3Bsd00002C37bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000010CFsd00001536bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000010CFsd0000147Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000010CFsd0000147Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv0000185Fsd0000309Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv00001A32sd00000306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000011ADsd00006642bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000011ADsd00006632bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv0000105Bsd0000E01Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv00001A3Bsd00001C71bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000029sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000027sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000024sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000023sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        ath9k_hw,mac80211,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:A1:7E:EF:58:C6:AC:5E:9A:85:71:2C:92:08:DF
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     696B00A6C59713EC0966997
depends:        ath,ath9k_hw
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:A1:7E:EF:58:C6:AC:5E:9A:85:71:2C:92:08:DF
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     4809F3842A0542CD6B556D3
depends:        ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:A1:7E:EF:58:C6:AC:5E:9A:85:71:2C:92:08:DF
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     88A67C5359B02C5A710AFCF
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:A1:7E:EF:58:C6:AC:5E:9A:85:71:2C:92:08:DF
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### modules #####

lp

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist gx1fb
blacklist gxfb
blacklist kyrofb
blacklist matroxfb_base
blacklist mb862xxfb
blacklist neofb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist pm2fb
blacklist pm3fb
blacklist s3fb
blacklist savagefb
blacklist sisfb
blacklist tdfxfb
blacklist tridentfb
blacklist viafb
blacklist vt8623fb

[/etc/modprobe.d/libpisock9.conf]
blacklist visor

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x8086:0x1050 (e100)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x168c:0x0023 (ath9k)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #####

[   10.844865] intel_rng: don't want to disable this in firmware setup, and if
[   13.545939] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x10
[   13.545940] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   13.545943] ath: Country alpha2 being used: CO
[   13.545944] ath: Regpair used: 0x10
[   18.175392] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   18.183358] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 6496.035165] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 6496.044241] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 6496.248022] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address removed> (try 2/3)
[ 6496.452023] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address removed> (try 3/3)
[ 6496.656020] wlan0: authentication with <MAC address removed> timed out
[ 6497.380862] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 6497.397872] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 6497.600021] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address removed> (try 2/3)
[ 6497.804021] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address removed> (try 3/3)
[ 6498.008021] wlan0: authentication with <MAC address removed> timed out
[ 6499.130876] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 6499.136436] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 6499.340021] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address removed> (try 2/3)
[ 6499.544021] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address removed> (try 3/3)
[ 6499.748020] wlan0: authentication with <MAC address removed> timed out
[ 6501.370856] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 6501.376427] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 6501.580023] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address removed> (try 2/3)
[ 6501.784021] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address removed> (try 3/3)
[ 6501.988022] wlan0: authentication with <MAC address removed> timed out
[ 6513.232923] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 6513.240608] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 6513.444022] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address removed> (try 2/3)
[ 6513.648023] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address removed> (try 3/3)
[ 6513.852019] wlan0: authentication with <MAC address removed> timed out

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Try with installing common wifi drivers and then open wicd. `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`

Comment: I did  as you instructed, then installed wicd(this was a new Lubuntu install so had to install it again). Wicd still returns the bad password error. I have read in some threads that having network-manager and wicd running at the same time is bad. I have tried running wicd without network-manager installed, but still no connection then, either. Perhaps some remnants of network-manager remain. Synaptic said it was all gone though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to install a new driver for your device because you have two error messages in dmesg:

1. ath: phy0: Failed to stop TX DMA, queues=0x001!
2. ath: Country alpha2 being used: CO

Go here [compat backports](http://drvbp1.linux-foundation.org/~mcgrof/rel-html/backports/) and download the newest driver to your computer then place the file on your desktop and right click and extract here.

After the file is on your desktop if you go to  home>username>Desktop>backports-3.15-rc1-1?drivers>net>wireless>ath this is in the file manager not the terminal then you will see the files with the same names as the ones I pasted.

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7486235/

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7486238

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7486250/

Open up your files one at a time delete what is in side then copy and paste my file of the same name into each file, be sure to copy the whole file and to save each one. Then recompile the driver using the directions below.

These commands will have to be ran each time there is an upgrade to the kernel.

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.15-rc1-1
make clean
make defconfig-ath9k
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv ath9k 
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

Do:

```
sudo apt-get install wireless-crda iw
```

Then:

```
sudo sed -i "s/REGDOMAIN=/REGDOMAIN=US/" /etc/default/crda
```

Then check if country code changed with:

```
iw reg get
```

You have to completely remove wicd or network manager you can not have them both installed at the same time.
Reboot